# Problem when trying to use kivy (python37)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, kivy

when i try to import a simple app with kivy i get this problem.
what do i do?

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="hello world")


if __import__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

problem i get:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dorijan\PycharmProjects\app1\app1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
  File "C:\Users\dorijan\PycharmProjects\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from kivy.compat import PY2
  File "C:\Users\dorijan\PycharmProjects\app1\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\compat.py", line 18, in <module>
    import Queue as queue
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Queue'
```

Comment: Not sure why the queue import would fail. But, what is the full traceback, it doesn't look like this is the original exception.

Comment: On the kivy homepage, it shows Python 2.7 - 3.4 - 3.5 - 3.6.
Maybe they don't support Python 3.7 yet (Talking about this page: https://kivy.org/#home)

Comment: The `Queue` module (with capital Q) is from Python 2.7. In Python 3, it was renamed as `queue` (lower case q). But not sure why that should matter with your App.

Answer (score 0):

so i got it to work, all i did was reinstall pycharm and kivy.But now i have another problem when i type the same code shown above I get info like this:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\dorijan\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-04-27_44.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.7 (v3.6.7:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 13:35:33) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
```

So everything seems to work right? but the window that is supposed to open that shows the "hello world" text doesnt open am I missing something?